# In python, with openCV, how to set correctly the maxRadius parameter of HoughCircles?

Tags: python, opencv

So I have this image (480, 640, 3):

[image: image with circles to detect]

And I want to do detect different circles in it (mainly the red one, but you don't care).

Here is my code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('img0.png')
print(img.shape)
sat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)[:, :, 1]
print(img.shape)
circles = circles = cv2.HoughCircles(sat, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=30, maxRadius=500)
print(circles)

if circles is not None: # code stolen from here : https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(img, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Note that I use the saturation for the gray image, as I want the red part of my hand spinner, it is easier for me

Which output this :

[image]

Which is not that bad for me(ignore the wrong color scheme, It's bgr of opencv displayed as rgb), except that there is circles with too big radius. The output of `print(circle)` is :

```
[[[420.5 182.5 141.3]
  [420.5 238.5  84.5]
  [335.5 283.5  35. ]
  [253.5 323.5  42.7]
  [417.5 337.5  43.6]]]
```

(it is [x,y, radius])

Basically, it means that circles of interest has radius below 50, and I want to get rid of the two first one. I wanted to use the maxRadius parameter (notice that in my code, it is currently 500). So my guess was that if I set maxRadius at 50, it would remove the unwanted radius, but instead, it deleted all the circles... I have found that with maxRadius at 400, I got an output that "works":
[image]

And with maxRadius below 200, there is no more circles found.

What I am missing here ?

I am working on windows, python 3.7.7, last version of opencv

Comment: The saturation channel is very noisy. If you really only want the one in the lower left, then do some median filtering, then threshold, since that circle is very bright and the others are not. Then use some morphology to clean up the image. Then do your hough circles. Or just get the contour of that circle and fit an ellipse. Average the radii and draw a circle.

Comment: yeah, I will just find another way, but it's kinda annoying that maxRadius didn't work as expected.

Comment: See my answer below. I just followed some of the tutorials and examples from a Google search and adjusted the param1 and param2.

Comment: Note, if I lower param2 from 50 to 30, I get too many circles, for example with `circles = cv2.HoughCircles(median, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=150, param2=30, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)`. But if I now put non-zero values for the minRadius and maxRadius, I can filter them out and get the same result as before: `circles = cv2.HoughCircles(median, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=150, param2=30, minRadius=30, maxRadius=100)`. So maxRadius does work. The keys is getting good values for minDist and param1 and param2

Comment: Thank you ! So if param1 and 2 aren't fixed, it does not make sense to tweak radius size.

Comment: Param1 and param2 defaults are 100 each. Param2 is the accumulator threshold, which is the count of pixels on the circle. If high it prevents small circles from the being detected. Apparently it is too high to detect the circles of your radius. So if no circles are detected, minRadius and maxRadius are meaningless. If you lower param 2 to 50, you will detect your circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input
- Convert to HSV and extract the saturation channel
- Median filter
- Do Hough Circles processing
- Draw the circles
- Save the results

Input

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read image
img = cv2.imread('circles.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# Convert to HSV and extract the saturation channel
sat = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)[:,:,1]

# median filter
median = cv2.medianBlur(sat, 7)

# get Hough circles
min_dist = int(ww/20)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(median, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, minDist=min_dist, param1=150, param2=50, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
print(circles)

# draw circles
result = img.copy()
for circle in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
    # corresponding to the center of the circle
    (x,y,r) = circle
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    cv2.circle(result, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
    cv2.rectangle(result, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('circles_saturation.jpg', sat)
cv2.imwrite('circles_median.jpg', sat)
cv2.imwrite('circles_result.jpg', result)

# show images
cv2.imshow('sat', sat)
cv2.imshow('median', median)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Saturation image:

[image]

Median filtered image:

[image]

Results:

[image]

Circles data:

```
[[[258.5 323.5  52.7]
  [340.5 193.5  51.3]
  [422.5 326.5  34.1]
  [333.5 276.5  33.6]]]
```